# Using Ng-Repeat to display data recursively

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table that looks like this

```
 _id    url     title   description 
   1   a.jsp     hi         hi
   2   a.jsp     hello      hello
   3   a.jsp     hey        hey
   4   b.jsp     hi         hi
   5   b.jsp     hello      hello
   6   b.jsp     hey        hey
```

I'm trying to print unique **url** as panel header where as corresponding title and description in panel body as a table. I'm not sure how to filter this

Expected output

```
a.jsp
 ->hi (_id=1)
 ->hello(_id=2)
 ->hey(_id=3)
b.jsp
 ->hi (_id=4)
 ->hello(_id=5)
 ->hey(_id=6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **groupBy** filter:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in table | groupBy: 'url'">
  Header: {{ key }}
    <li ng-repeat="row in value">
        title: {{ row.title}} 
        id: {{ row.id}} 
    </li>
</ul>
```

More docs here: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Comment: worked well and angular-filter.js looks very helpful. Thanks a lot !